# Notation: operations with one-hot matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix formed by one-hot encoding, e.g.

$$X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

I can use it to "expand" diagonal matrices

$$ D= \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b \end{pmatrix} = D_{\exp} $$

What's the best way to denote this operation for the purposes of deriving identities with it?

So far all I have is
$$ X D = D_{\exp} X $$

Comment: Would be good if you would be able to provide a more general principle of what you expect. IMHO, a single example may not represent what you have in mind. Up to now, we're forced to only guess what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you have $X \in \{0, 1\}^{n \times c}$, where $n$ is the number of items and $c$ is the number of classes, $D \in \mathcal{R}^{c \times c}$ that is a diagonal matrix representing the classes.
Specifically, $X_{ij} = 1$ iff item-$i$ is in class $j$, and $D_{jj}$ is the "symbol" of class-$j$.
Therefore, $XD$ has the same size as $X$ and the positions of non-zero entries are the same as in $X$, where each non-zero $XD_{ij} = D_{jj}$.
You want to expand $D$ to $D_{exp} \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n}$ that is a diagonal matrix too.
If I understand it correctly, the diagonal of $D_{exp}$ should just be the array of the classes of the $n$ items.
Specifically, for each $i$, ${D_{exp}}_{ii} = D_{jj}$ such that $X_{ij} = 1$.